# What does “No protocol specified” mean with X11?

Tags: xorg

I am running X11:

```
$ ps aux | grep Xorg
root       2052  0.0  0.0 263544 49668 tty1     Sl+  18:42   0:00 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
```

When I run glxinfo I get this error:

```
$ glxinfo
No protocol specified
Error: unable to open display :0
```

I can see there is a display available, if I run this:

```
$ (cd /tmp/.X11-unix && for x in X*; do echo ":${x#X}"; done)
:0
```

If I were to run vncserver, I could get glxinfo output something useful: `glxinfo -display :1`

Why can't I in this case with a localhost display running on display 0, screen 0?